# Map what my software is using on a linux system

Tags: python, linux

Is there a Linux program I can use to map everything my software is using and translate that into a package list?  I was thinking I could use strace start mapping files from there.  Specifically I'm looking at a python script but I would like something generic.

I might just need the right term for this practice.

Thank you,

Comment: If you mean all of the python packages, use virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper.   You will need to use pip to install required packages.  Then use pip freeze to list all packages you have installed

Comment: I was hoping for the external requirements also.  For example so files that are used.  For example "/lib64/libdl-2.17.so" is used when I start python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a Debian derivative, you should be able to use the truly wonderful command [dpkg-depcheck](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/dpkg-depcheck/en/) to run your software and get a list of packages it depends on (basically, it automates what it sounds like you're proposing to do manually: running it under strace and then cross-referencing the files accessed with the packages providing them).

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing usually depends on the package manager.  For example, on ArchLinux with packman, you'd use

```
pacman -Q
```

for Debian based distributions, you might use

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

Obviously package manager only knows about packages it has installed itself. For example, python packages installed by `pip` won't be known to the distro package manager.